# MySQL stored procedure consuming 1:8 times with parameter variable

Tags: mysql

The SQL statement execute at 0.019 sec when i use literal like '12345' in the SQL statement WHERE class, but the same UDP consumes 4.19 sec when i use the IN parameter

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test_PFM`(IP_param  VARCHAR(6))
    BEGIN
    /*
    test query speed
    purpose:
    Use compare query out pu

    Bug: 
     UDP takes 4 seconds when 
    locojourney.LocoNumber = IP_param  

    where as if locojourney.LocoNumber = '11516'
    executes at 0.019 second

    */

    DECLARE Output VARCHAR(1) ;

    SELECT locojourney.IShoc 
    INTO Output
    FROM locojourney 
    WHERE
    locojourney.JourneySerla = (
    SELECT MAX(locojourney.JourneySerla) FROM locojourney 
    WHERE locojourney.LocoNumber = '11516') LIMIT 1;

    SELECT Output;


    END;
```

Comment: I hope you know that SQL tables/resultsets are by SQL standards definition **orderless**.. Meaning `LIMIT` without using `ORDER BY` is **meaningless** and will give **non deterministic (random)** results?

Comment: Also can you show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE locojourney` output?

Comment: Is your LocoNumber an actual string or numeric value.  If numeric, get rid of your quotes and change your parameter to a numeric, not string parameter.

Comment: Oh my god Loconumber field is a SMALLINT(5) i was comparing int to string, HatsUp to Mr Raymod and Mr DRapp, lot of thanks, let me know how to rate your answer please

Answer (score 0):

my sincere thanks to Mr Raymond and Mr DRapp for pointing me in right direction, actually i was comaring string to a smallint field.
please mark thread as resolved.